# Grails application can't find Weblogic home

Tags: tomcat, grails, weblogic

I have grails Application(application itself is built on groovy).
Application has some weblogic dependencies, so following line is added to build.config:
    provided 'weblogic:wlfullclient:10.3.3.0.0'

I was able to get it working with grails run-app command after modifying classpath in startGrails.bat with weblogic.jar.

However, when I try to simply deploy war file to tomcat(simply copying it to 
webapps directory, application. I receive an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error in finding weblogic.Home
    at weblogic.Home.getInstance(Home.java:91)
    at weblogic.Home.getPath(Home.java:97)
    at weblogic.Home.getFile(Home.java:102)
    at weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTInterpreter.<init>(WLSTInterpreter.java:116)
    at weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTInterpreter.<init>(WLSTInterpreter.java:76)
    at somepackage.someclass.<init>(someclass.groovy:19)
    ... 5 more
```

I have tried updating Tomcat lib directory with this jar, aplication lib directory, tried to pass weblogic home as java parameter in catalina.bat. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
catalina.bat contains following:
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dweblogic.home="C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3 -Dgrails.home=C:\apps\grails-1.3.7 -Dgrails.version=1.3.7 -Dgroovy.starter.conf=C:\apps\grails-1.3.7\conf\groovy-starter.conf -Dtools.jar=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\lib\tools.jar"

set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\apps\grails-1.3.7\lib\groovy-all-1.7.8.jar;C:\apps\grails-1.3.7\dist\grails-bootstrap-1.3.7.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar"

%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" -classpath "%CLASSPATH%" -Dcatalina.base="%CATALINA_BASE%" -Dcatalina.home="%CATALINA_HOME%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CATALINA_TMPDIR%" %MAINCLASS% %CMD_LINE_ARGS% %ACTION%
```

Comment: Is weblogic.jar not being pulled in by the build system as a dependency?

Comment: Can you show your command line/.bat where `-Dmw.home=` is set?

Comment: Description updated.